# How to decrease an exponent

Tags: binary

I have this number:

$$ 0.2 = 1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 \times 2^{-3}$$

I want to have the exponent to equal `-4`. Should I just move the radix point to the right one place like so?

$$ 1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 \times 2^{-3} =\\
11.001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 \times 2^{-4}$$

Comment: Obviously you moved it to the **right** - but this is correct.

Comment: yes, this was a typo, thanks!